# A work in progress answer, kept deleted until it's done

Tags: discussion

Is this allowed? It's handy, working in JavaScript, using the snippet window for development. Updating the (deleted) answer gives source control functionality for free.

On the other hand, that can be annoying for users that see also the deleted answers.

Comment: For me the only annoyance comes from the fact that “comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews”, so I cannot post improvement suggestions for them.

Comment: @manatwork You also can't do that if it wasn't posted in the first place ;)

Comment: You could get essentially the same benefits with jsfiddle, couldn't you?

Comment: @PeterTaylor essentially, yes. But having all in a single place, tied to my StackExchange login, is easier

Answer (score 6):

I agree that it can be annoying for high rep users, but I think its totally valid for a user to delete his answer and then later undelete it for any reason, not just WIP.